# How can I fetch data from a model database to fill up another model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am still a beginner in rails. I want to populate some form field in a model with another model's data already in database based on an association selection. Below are my codes.

**Stock Purchase model**

```
class StockPurchase < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :stock
end
```

**Stock Model**

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :stock_purchases
end
```

**Stock Purchase form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@stock_purchase) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
      <%= f.association :stock, prompt: "Select Product", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :expiry_date, input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
    <%= f.input :selling_price, as: :currency, input_html: { class: "form-control", placeholder: "Selling Price" } %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**My controller**

```
def new
    @stock_purchase = current_user.stock_purchases.build
    @stocks = Stock.all 
end
```

From the form, I want to fill up the expiry date and selling price from database based on the selected stock.

Please how do I go about it.

Comment: have you got any code in your controller?

Comment: do you only have "new" in your controller, or do you have "edit" as well?  is the "form" you've posted above reused for both "new" and "edit"?

Comment: since it's new method your just created "@stock_purchase" has nil fields you have to fill them before they will go to your form. Try  in controller "@stock_purchase.expiry_date = DateTime.now"

Comment: Thanks snake for your comment but what i want to achieve is that when a stock is selected from the stock select field, the expiry date and selling price should be fetched from the selected stock database table with the selected stock id and fill up the expiry date and selling price

Comment: U could use JS to achieve that. Create an event listener that fires if the select is changed. Let it do an AJAX request to the server and then send back the data you need.

Comment: As Hackman says, the only way to do what you want is in JavaScript.  if you wanted to do this without JavaScript, you'd want to have an index page of all your stock, with an action leading to "stock_purchase_path" passing in the stock object/id.

Answer (score 0):

This will show the stocks in a dropdown select field, the user chooses the stock then you can extract the expiry date and selling price in the controller, just of course switch the variables to what you have set

```
<%= f.field_container :stock do %>
  <%= f.label :stock %>
  <%= f.select :stock_id, options_for_select(Stock.all.map{|s|[s.name, s.id]}) %>
<% end %>
```

however you don't have to extract these attributes and repeat yourself in the Stock Purchase because you can just call the attributes (selling price, expiry date) from the children of Stock Purchase like

`StockPurchase.stocks.all.first.selling_price`

but ofcourse it depends on how you named your variables

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really want to have it done using javascript/jquery or ajax in a way after selecting the stock, it automatically fetch the stock selling price and expiry date from database and use it to fill the selling price and expiry date input field. I still cannot figure it out